# Нужна ли запятая после "Так"?

Tags: пунктуация

Слухи о любовных похождениях Синатры не могли пройти мимо него самого. Так в 1966 году Синатра женился на молодой актрисе Миа Фэрроу.

Answer (score 4):

Согласна с Софией. Формально запятая нужна. Но явная логическая ошибка: вопреки ожидаемому, смысл второго предложения никак не подтверждает содержание перового. А должен бы, так как начинается с вводного "так".

Comment: Это не второе, а первое предложение составлено коряво. И (не знаю, какой здесь можно подобрать термин) претендует (автор вопроса нас принуждает) на импликацию со вторым. А второе вот вполне самостоятельное: "Так он познакомился с тремя девушками за один день". Как *так*? А посетив несколько массовых городских мероприятий. И без запятой. 
А можно и с запятой — если правильно придумать предыдущее предложение.

Comment: Домыслить можно разное. В ответе исходила из того, есть. Честно говоря, надоело додумывать, что именно хочет сказать автор текста. Возможно, первое предложение является вступительным. Со второго начинается история. Далее должно быть понятно, что услышал Синатра о своей женитьбе.

Comment: Текст из Интернета.
3. Синатра известнем всем как большой любитель женщин, о его романах ходит множество слухов. Он был женат четыре раза, однако самым продолжительным был последний брак с Барбарой Маркс. Слухи о любовных похождениях Синатры не могли пройти мимо него самого, так в 1966 году Синатра женился на молодой актрисе Миа Фэрроу, ей был 21 год, ему 51. В прессе критиковали этот брак, и Синатра нанимал людей для расправы над критиками и своими недоброжелателями.
Явно первое предложение должно заканчиваться точкой, а далее слово ТАК начинает новую тему.

Comment: Сама долго не могла понять логику автора, но думала, это я такая непонятливая... Взято из газетной статьи, как верно подметили выше. Короче, я поняла, что лучше вообще убрать это "Так", чем морочить себе голову. Спасибо за помощь))

Comment: > Слухи о любовных похождениях Синатры не могли пройти мимо него самого,

Слухи сами заворачивали к нему на огонёк... Ну чепуха же!.. Какие слухи?!
Посмею догадаться, что дело было несколько иначе. 
*Пересуды о любовных похождениях не оставляли равнодушным самого Синатру. Так, когда в газетах критиковали его брак <...> Синатра нанимал людей для расправы...*

Answer (score 3):

Если смотреть только на форму предложения, то запятая после ТАК нужна. Это вводное слово со значением НАПРИМЕР.Похожий вариант: Его скопидомство доходило до крайности: так, он целый год писал одним пером.Однако, с точки зрения смысла, предложение выглядит  странно - возможно, оно составлено неправильно. Скорее всего, со слова ТАК нужно начать новое предложение и далее раскрывать тему.